# Helm service not deploying to Microk8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, microk8s

I'm trying to deploy a service I created to kubernetes using Helm. Helm's telling me it's deploying but a "get pods" doesn't show me any pod deployed.

As you can see below postgres is getting deployed, so this isn't an issue with my helm/k8s setup. Instead it's with my specific service, however since no error messages are printed I don't know what the problem is.

```
$ helm upgrade --install postgres stable/postgres
Release "postgres" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: postgres
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Nov 24 18:04:52 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 8
TEST SUITE: None

$ helm upgrade --install my-service $HOME/proj/my-service
Release "my-service" has been upgraded. Happy Helming!
NAME: my-service
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Nov 24 18:02:51 2020
NAMESPACE: default                                                                                                     
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 8
TEST SUITE: None                                          

$ microk8s kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
postgres-postgresql-0   1/1     Running   1          3h

$
```

And the $HOME/proj/my-service/templates/job.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-service
        image: alpine:latest
        command: 
        - "yes"
```

Comment: Are there any Deployments or StatefulSets, or anything else that would deploy a Pod, in your chart?  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes there is a job.yaml in the my-service directory. Will add

Comment: Have you also checked other namespaces? `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces'

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes. Dashboard, coredns, calico all show up but the service I'm trying to start does not.

Comment: @rsnakard-r7 Sorry for the the late response. Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: I ended up deleting all my files and reinstalling helm and microk8s. Then everything worked.